# Disable my-location when user moves the map and re-enable when he press the my-location button

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm using the `setMyLocationEnabled(true)` from **Google Maps Android API v2** to have auto location tracking and to display the indicator just like Google Maps app. I need that the camera position follows the my-location indicator so it will be always visible, except when the user pans the map.

So, I'm using the `onMyLocationChange` method to move the camera to the new location, but when the user pans the map or use the search field from my app, the `onMyLocationChange` continues being called and the camera always comes back to the my-location coordinates.

How can I move the camera automatically when my-location is enabled, disable it when the map is manually manipulated (pan, rotate or search) and enable it back when the user press the my-location button?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**

There is now `GoogleMap.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener`, so you can skip point 1 and use that.

---

You can't do that with the february version of the Maps API v2. The best thing you can do is to:

1. have your own "go to my location" button to know when you want to start tracking
2. your own location change listener
3. a `View` on top of `SupportMapFragment` with `onTouchListener` (returning `false`!) to know when you need to stop tracking

This solution is not perfect, as it will stop tracking before user zooms on pans - it will stop when they first touch the map, but I think it is a solution that will not make any confusion for users: they touched the map, so can expect tracking to stop and can press the button to start it.

Answer (score 0):

So Why don't you just why don't you just call `setMyLocationEnabled(false)` When user interacts with the `TextView`?

The only interaction you can check with the map is:

```
map.setOnMapClickListener(listener);
map.setOnMapLongClickListener(listener);
map.setOnMarkerClickListener(listener);
map.setOnMarkerDragListener(listener);
```

You could do the same thing for those interaction to disable the `my-location layer`.

Comment: If I do disable it, the my location button will be removed.

Comment: I never used the setMyLocationEnabled method, do you have an onLocationChangeListenr and onMyLocationChange methods? If yes then do your onMyLocationChange operations only if the user doesn't interact with the TextView or the map. check it with TextWatcher and the methods for the map I provided in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Remove these two lines(if you have) from within the method

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
      //Remove these two lines
      googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
      googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can detect a user gesture by using the REASON_GESTURE from the setOnCameraMoveStartedListener.

```
mMap.setOnCameraMoveStartedListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveStartedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCameraMoveStarted(int reason) {
        if (reason == GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveStartedListener.REASON_GESTURE) {
            //Camera motion initiated in response to user gestures on the map.
        } else if (reason == GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveStartedListener.REASON_API_ANIMATION){
            //Non-gesture animation initiated in response to user actions.
        } else if (reason == GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveStartedListener.REASON_DEVELOPER_ANIMATION){
            //Developer initiated animation.
        }
    }
});
```

See the doc for more details: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveStartedListener