# Google Maps Distinguish between User Move and Animation

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

I'm working with Google Maps API V2, and I'm wondering if there is a way to distinguish between when the user interacts with the map to move or zoom the camera, and when the animateCamera method is called.

What I want to do is have the map center on the user following them until they zoom in or drag the map away, at which point I want to give the user full control.

My issue is that onCameraChange gets called both when the user moves the map, and when the map is animated. What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To distinguish animateCamera from other moves, you can use code in comment here: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4636#c21

If you are using the myLocation button in the top right corner, this won't work, because you can't distinguish pressing it (when you want to start tracking user position) from other user actions. See: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4789

For best user experience as of 3.1.36 I suggest following this answer: [Disable my-location when user moves the map and re-enable when he press the my-location button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15829938/disable-my-location-when-user-moves-the-map-and-re-enable-when-he-press-the-my-l/15836770#15836770)

Answer (score 19):

There is a nice callback from GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveStartedListener described [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/events)

Point is:

```
@Override
public void onCameraMoveStarted(int reason) {

    if (reason == OnCameraMoveStartedListener.REASON_GESTURE) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "The user gestured on the map.",
                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (reason == OnCameraMoveStartedListener
                            .REASON_API_ANIMATION) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "The user tapped something on the map.",
                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (reason == OnCameraMoveStartedListener
                            .REASON_DEVELOPER_ANIMATION) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "The app moved the camera.",
                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: you saved my night! Thanks!!

Comment: So simple this is a great answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you're animating the map, the `CancelableCallback` you pass in allows you to detect if

- the animated finished succesfully (meaning that the user didn't interrupt the animation, providing you didn't call `stopAnimation` yourself.)
- the animation was cancelled (animationCancelled) meaning that the user interrupted it by interacting with the map).

As you know

- when the animation was started
- when the animation was completed
- when the animation was interrupted by the user

you should have sufficient state information in your activity / fragment to decide that the user interacted with the map while doing your animation. At that point you can decide not to animate the map anymore. (by avoiding subsequent calls to animateCamera.